# Stubbing ES6 function import in mocha using sinon stub

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, babeljs, sinon, supertest

I'm trying to stub function called on one of my routes in express Router with request from supertest library. I see that function foo is called correctly, unfortunately it is not replaced by stub function I wrote in test. Code is written in ES6 and I'm using `babel-register` and `babel-polyfill` to make it work.

I run testing script using

```sh
./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha server --timeout 10000 --compilers js:babel-register --require babel-polyfill --recursive
```

router.js

```
import {foo} from '../controller';
const router = new Router();
router.route(ROUTE).post(foo);
```

controller.js

```
export function foo(req, res) {
    res.status(200).send({
        ok: 'ok'
    });
}
```

test.js

```
import request from 'supertest';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import {app} from 'app';
import * as controller from 'controller';

const agent = request.agent(app);
describe('Admin routes tests', () => {
    it('Tests login admin route', async () => {
    const bar = () => {
        console.log('bar');
    };
    sinon.stub(controller, 'foo', bar);
    const req = await agent
        .post(ROUTE)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json');
    console.log(stub.calledOnce); // false
    });
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this @ruciu?

Comment: As far as I remember I gave up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution:

`app.js`:

```js
import express from "express";
import * as controller from "./controller";

const app = express();

app.post("/foo", controller.foo);

export { app };
```

`controller.js`:

```js
export function foo(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send({ ok: "ok" });
}
```

`test.js`:

```js
import request from "supertest";
import sinon from "sinon";
import * as controller from "./controller";
import { expect } from "chai";

describe("Admin routes tests", () => {
  it("Tests login admin route", (done) => {
    const bar = () => {
      console.log("bar");
    };
    const fooStub = sinon.stub(controller, "foo").callsFake(bar);
    const { app } = require("./app");
    const agent = request.agent(app);
    agent
      .post("/foo")
      .set("Accept", "application/json")
      .timeout(1000)
      .end((err, res) => {
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(fooStub);
        expect(res).to.be.undefined;
        expect(err).to.be.an.instanceof(Error);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

Since you stub `foo` controller and its return value is `undefined`. For `supertest`, there is no response, something like `res.send()`, the server will hang until the mocha test timeout and it will cause test failed.

`.mocharc.yml`:

```
recursive: true
require: ts-node/register
timeout: 2000
diff: true
inline-diffs: true
```

We add `.timeout(1000)` for supertest, because we know it will timeout(You stub the `foo` controller with `bar`). And, make an assertion for this timeout error.

Integration test result with coverage report:

```sh
  Admin routes tests
bar
    ✓ Tests login admin route (1341ms)


  1 passing (1s)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |    95.65 |      100 |       80 |    95.65 |                   |
 app.ts        |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 controller.ts |       50 |      100 |        0 |       50 |                 2 |
 test.ts       |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/41600031

Comment: Thank you for answer, I thought I will never know why this failed.